# Arithmetic syntax in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic

I am getting the below error on arithmetic values

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
line_count=9
line_count=$(line_count)/3
echo $line_count
exit 0
```

expected result is 3

```
[]$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 4: line_count: command not found
/3
[]$ more test.sh
```

Comment: Check the placement of your parantheses.

Answer (score 10):

To complement [@Kusalananda's answer](/a/345450), in addition to the standard `sh` syntax:

```
line_count=$((line_count / 3))
```

In `bash` you can also use these syntaxes inherited from `ksh` (also work in `zsh`):

- ```
  ((line_count = line_count / 3))
  ```
- ```
  ((line_count /= 3))
  ```
- ```
  let line_count/=3
  ```
- ```
  typeset -i line_count; line_count=line_count/3
  ```

`bash` (and `zsh`) also support:

- ```
  line_count=$[line_count/3]
  ```

For old pre-POSIX Bourne/Almquist `sh`:

```
line_count=`expr "$line_count" / 3`
```

Answer (score 6):

Arithmetic expansion is done by `bash` and some other shells with `$(( ... ))`, e.g.

```
line_count=$(( line_count/3 ))
```

With `line_count=$(line_count)/3`, you are assigning the output of the command `line_count` to the variable `line_count`, suffixed by `/3`.

This is why you get the error "line_count: command not found" and then the output `/3`.

Have a look at ShellCheck at https://www.shellcheck.net/
It is able to check you script for common issues. In this case, it won't help you with spotting that `$(...)` should have been `$((...))` but that's because `$(line_count)` is perfectly legal shell code. It just does the wrong thing.